# How to define my resource class?

Tags: web-applications, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am newbie in RESTful Jersey. If I have a car resource:

```
@Path("/car")
public class CarResource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Car getCar(@QueryParam("id") String id) {

        Car mycar = new Car(id);
        return mycar;
    }
}
```

I can send request **BASE_URL/car?id='d12'** to server. Things are fine here.

How about sending a request like **BASE_URL/car/color-by-id?id='d12'** ? should I define **another** resource class like:

```
@Path("/car/color-by-id")
    public class ColorByIdResource {
        @GET
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public ColorById getColorById(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
                       ....
        }
}
```

I kind dislike the above **ColorByIdResource**, and prefer to define it inside **CarResource**, the question is how can I define this inside **CarResource** then?

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
@Path("/car")
public class CarResource {

        @GET
        @Path("color-by-id")
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public ColorById getColorById(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
                       ....
        }
}
```